# Bibtex "Author with contributions" wrong sorting

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

See this bibtex entry (gotten directly from R using `citation()`):

```
@Manual{demography,
  title = {demography: Forecasting mortality, fertility, migration and population data},
  author = {Rob J Hyndman with contributions from Heather Booth and Leonie Tickle and John Maindonald and Simon Wood and R Core Team.},
  year = {2012},
  note = {R package version 1.14},
  url = {http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=demography},
}
```

Since the main author is `Rob J Hyndman`, I'd expect bibtex together with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to put this reference as `H`, ie. between `G` and `I`. Now, it's somewhere in the middle of `W`s, which doesn't look right.

It gets print as:

```
Rob J Hyndman with contributions from Heather Booth, Leonie Tickle, John Maindonald,
Simon Wood, and R Core Team. demography: Forecasting mortality, fertility, migration
and population data, 2012. R package version 1.14.
```

How do I get it to print in the "right" place?

Comment: The sorting is correct. The string `Rob J Hyndman with contributions from Heather Booth` counts as a single name.

Comment: I know that bibtex is doing it right, but [here's a screen](http://screencloud.net/v/35jU) of the document. The sorting looks off. How would I fix that?

Comment: @Mico: WIth correct I mean: Without special handling the entry is sorted correct after the rules of BibTeX.

Comment: I ended up replacing `with` with `and`. Hope it's ok, when it prints `Rob J Hyndman, contributions from George Athanasopoulos, Slava Razbash, Drew Schmidt, Zhenyu Zhou, and Yousaf Khan. forecast: Forecasting functions for time series and linear models, 2013. R package version 4.03.`.

Comment: @PetrMarek - I've come up with a method that inserts the string "with contributions from" in the references while still sorting the entry under `H` for Hyndman...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preface: Even though the locution "with contributions from" is used in the reference on `R`'s website, *you* shouldn't feel compelled to use it for a bib entry in *your* document. Using the simple `and` connector between the first and subsequent authors is perfectly legitimate in the present case -- and doing so avoids all kinds of tricky complications.

***However***, if you really, truly, absolutely prefer to provide the string "with contributions from" in the bibliography (while, of course, still keeping the entry sorted under `H` for Hyndman!), you can do so with the following, admittedly somewhat kludgy method: Use both the `and` connector *and* the string `{\relax with contributions from}`, as in the following entry:

```
@manual{demography,
  title =  {demography: {Forecasting} mortality, fertility, migration and population data},
  author = {Rob J. Hyndman and {\relax with contributions from} 
            Heather Booth and Leonie Tickle and John Maindonald and Simon Wood and {R Core Team}},
  year =   {2012},
  note =   {R package version 1.14},
  url =    {http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=demography},
}
```

Observe that I'd make two further changes to the bib entry. First, I'dencase the final author (`R Core Team`) in curly braces to inform BibTeX that it's a "corporate" author -- for which no parts should be abbreviated (say, as "R.C. Team"...) even if the bibliography style in use is set to abbreviate first and middle names down to their first initials. Second, I'd encase the word `Forecasting` in the title field in curly braces; doing so prevents the `F` from being converted to `f` if "sentence- style" typesetting of entries of `title` fields is practiced by the bibliography style you use.

Assuming this entry is contained in a file named `hyndman.bib`, the following MWE, which uses the `plainnat` bibliography style,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % use author-year citation style
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % simplify color scheme ...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{demography}
\bibliography{hyndman}
\end{document}
```

generates this output:

[image]

A caveat: This method won't work perfectly if you use a bibliography style (such as `chicago`) that abbreviates first and middle names down to their initials. For instance, if you used the bibliography style `chicago`, you'd get *Hyndman, R. J., with contributions from Heather Booth, L. Tickle, ...*; note that Ms. Booth's first name wouldn't be truncated.  I guess you could fix this minor issue by entering her name as "H. Booth".

*Postscript*: Once the additional keyword `and` has been inserted after the first author's name, why bother encasing the string `with contributions from` in a `{\relax ...}` construct? The `\relax` directive "hides" the rest of the stuff in curly braces from BibTeX (though not from LaTeX). This is useful just in case you have two entries, one with a name field such as "Rob J. Hyndman and {\relax with contributions from} Heather Booth and Leonie Tickle" and another with a name field such as "Rob J. Hyndman and Homer Buster and Leonard Trinket" (i.e., with Messrs Buster and Trinket being listed as "full-fledged" authors). If you didn't hide the "with contributions from" string from BibTeX, the former entry would be listed *after* the latter, even though "Heather Booth" would normally be considered to come before "Homer Buster"...

Comment: Thanks Mico, I ended up replacing `with` with `and`, as proposed in the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

There is no provision in BibTeX for "with contributions from" in the author field. What are the possible strategies for this entry?

1. Remove the contributors from the author field.
2. Remove the contributors from the author field and put them in the `note` field.
3. Sort manually this entry.

The last way requires rewriting the entry:

```
author={{\NOOPSORT{Hyndman}Rob J. Hyndman, with contributions from Heather Booth, 
         Leonie Tickle, John Maindonald, Simon Wood, and R Core Team.}}
```

In full:

```
@Manual{demography,
  title = {demography: {Forecasting} mortality, fertility, migration and population data},
    author={{\NOOPSORT{Hyndman}Rob J. Hyndman, with contributions from Heather Booth, 
             Leonie Tickle, John Maindonald, Simon Wood, and R Core Team.}},
  year = {2012},
  note = {R package version 1.14},
  url = {http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=demography},
}
```

You have also to add to your document preamble

```
\newcommand{\NOOPSORT}[1]{}
```

so that the bit used for sorting will be ignored.

**Limitation.** This formatting is tailored to what is output by the `plain` BibTeX style. You may have to manually change it if another style is used.