# Proper alphabetization of BibTeX entries having "with so-and-so" (second author)

Tags: bibtex

This question is closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113919/bibtex-author-with-contributions-wrong-sorting), but for a number of subtle reasons, that solution does not work

I'm running *TeXShop* v. 3.96 using `tufte-book` style and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, and would like to include a reference that has a primary author and a subsidiary (or "with help from") author.

The problem arises in the alphabetization (ordering) of the references:  It *should* be under "Silverman" but is *instead* under "Whitney".  I've tried a number of variations in the following entry (including `and`, grouping different elements in brackets, and such), but none work:

```
    @BOOK{SilvermanWhitney:12,
           AUTHOR = "Peter Silverman {\relax with Catherine Whitney}",
            TITLE = "Leonardo\rq s lost princess:  {O}ne man\rq s quest to
 authenticate an unknown portrait by {L}eonardo da {V}inci",
        PUBLISHER = "Wiley", 
          ADDRESS = "New York, NY",
             YEAR = "2012"
    }
```

I use both `\cite{}` (for margin citations) and `\citep{}` for a special bibliographic section of the book.  Of course the margin citations (`\cite{}`) are fine, since there is no alphabetization:

[image]

But for the `\citep{}` I get an error in the body of the text:

[image]

(I would be happy to get either "Silverman and Whitney, 2012" or "Silverman, 2012", whichever is simpler.)

I also get the core problem:  a mis-alphabetization in the bibliography:

[image]

I'm happy to kludge the above single .bib entry, so long as the reference is typeset and alphabetized correctly.  (I'm not going to alter the code of BibTeX itself.)

How shall I alter the entry to this end?

Comment: Please advise (a) whether you use authoryear-style or numeric-style citation call-outs and, assuming you use authoryear-style call-outs, (b) whether you expect the citation call-out to say "Silverman (2012)", "Silverman and Whitney (2012)", or something else.

Comment: If you do `author="Peter Silverman {\relax with Catherine Whitney}"`, you're defining a person who has “Peter” as first name, “Silverman” as middle name, and a very peculiar last name “with Catherine Whitney”. BibTeX doesn't support “with”.

Comment: @egreg:  Thanks.  Yes... I found that out through extensive trial and error.  So is there really no hope here?

Comment: Are you forced to use `natbib`? This would be a lot easier to do I think with `biblatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn:  After a year of writing, 511 pages (and counting), I'm not eager to switch from `natbib`.  But just as a hypothetical:  What .bib entry would work if I used instead `biblatex`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple solution using `biblatex` based on the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67902/2693). Since `biblatex` has a `natbib` option to support `natbib` cite commands, it may be  fairly simple to adapt your existing document to using it. I've used the standard `authoryear` style in the example, there are plenty of other possibilities.  In this example, I've put the collaborating author at the end, which is a fairly standard way to do it. If you absolutely must have the "with Author" immediately after the main author's name, this would require a bit more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @BOOK{SilvermanWhitney:12,
           AUTHOR = "Peter Silverman",
            TITLE = "Leonardo\rq s lost princess:  {O}ne man\rq s quest to
 authenticate an unknown portrait by {L}eonardo da {V}inci",
        PUBLISHER = "Wiley", 
          ADDRESS = "New York, NY",
             YEAR = "2012", 
           EDITOR = "Catherine Whitney",
        EDITORTYPE = "collaborator"
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{bycollaborator={with}}

\begin{document}
\citet{SilvermanWhitney:12}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The "EDITOR" idea is fine (+1).  I tried "NOTE" as well which seems to be equivalent..